# Where can I ask "Find a tool"-Questions?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

**Where can I ask questions like:**

"Do you know a tool/program for doing ...?"

"Are there alternatives to the software ... ?"

Comment: Nowhere on our network.

Comment: For your second question, try http://alternativeto.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere on Stack Exchange.

These types of questions don't fit with our Q&A format. Questions are expected to have **one** correct answer, and these types of "poll" questions don't work with Stack Exchange. Also, these types of questions tend to attract spam answers.

**However**, if [Software Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) ever gets into public beta, it *might* be okay to ask there. I'm not sure that site will end well, though....

You could also try http://slant.co; they've got a good platform for those types of questions.

Comment: That site will not end well. I'm surprised they're even considering it. That will just end up being a spam fiesta and a lot of confused moderators wondering "Am I supposed to mark this spam flag as helpful or decline it?" Where would you draw the line?

Comment: @animuson Think positive. Find the silver-lining.

Comment: @animuson we'll find out.... private beta is launching soon

Comment: Of course *Software Recommendations* will work :) And if OP joins now he can even participate in the private beta.

Comment: @animuson: *We wouldn't be supporting this proposal if we didn't think it had a chance of working.* [Source](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13031/laying-some-ground-rules-for-software-recommendations)

Comment: Or if they didn't think it would generate lots of ad impressions.